# how to add more than one android app to your firebase project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

Is it possible to add more than one android app to the same project in the firebase console?
I've been trying to find the answer and it seems like the interface has changed or I just can't find the right place to add an additional app to the project.
basically i'd like to have more than one app listed here where it says "your apps":

[image]

maybe i'm missing something but as far as I understood this is the way to get a google-services.json file that I can use for FCM.
(if this is the wrong way to go about that please do tell :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is, you can add more than one app to your firebase project:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

in case you are missing firebase **Add App** button you can follow this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you.  turns out i just didn't see that UI because i didn't have administrator permissions for that project.  ugh :)